# Magento 2 install clean up

Tags: magento2, installation, setup

Is there a way of nicely cleaning up the magento root folder after the site is set up eg files like php.ini.sample and folders like /setup?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean for backed?

Comment: `/setup` folder is required for backend